# How to find the complex numbers from the given equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

as I'm doing a revision of the math question. I'm kinda stuck with this question... is there any solution to solve it?? As I convert it to $v=iw-5$, $w=-(3i/(1+2i)v)$,not sure how to proceed as $x$ and $y$ are real.

Text From Image:
The complex numbers $v$ and $w$ satisfy the equations:
$$v+iw = 5 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ (1+2i)v-w = 3i$$
Solve for $v$ and $w$, giving your answers in the form $x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are real.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELeMd.jpg)

Comment: Just write $v=a+i\,b$ and $w=c+i\,d$, replace and compare

Comment: Let me try it, thanks for the tips.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: another way would be to substitute the value of $v$ from equation 1 into equation 2

Comment: Hi, do you mean by doing expansion first and then substituting it?

Comment: well I see that @mrtechtoid has already given an answer.

Comment: also, if you want to reply to me (or anyone else) write @ and their username, like ```@DS```, otherwise if we are viewing some other question, we don't get to know you've replied to us

Comment: Something must have happened to you to already get $v = iw - 5$ instead of what should be $v = 5 - iw$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you learned for solving systems of linear equations with real coefficients still "works" for equations with complex-number coefficients.  Just to show that matrices can also used (should you have learned how to work with them), we can write your system as
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}  1 & i \\ 1 + 2i & -1 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} v \\ w \end{array} \right] \  =  \ \left[ \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 3i \end{array} \right] \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{c} v \\ w \end{array} \right] \  =  \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}  1 & i \\ 1 + 2i & -1 \end{array} \right]^{-1} \left[ \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 3i \end{array} \right] \ \ ;  $$
we compute the inverse matrix by
$$ \det \  \left|\begin{array}{cc } 1 & i \\ 1 + 2i & -1 \end{array} \right| \ \ = \ \ 1·(-1) \ - \ (1 + 2i)·i \ \ = \ \ 1 - i $$
$$ \rightarrow \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}  1 & i \\ 1 + 2i & -1 \end{array} \right]^{-1} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{1 - i} \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}  -1 & -i \\ -1 - 2i & 1 \end{array} \right] \ \ = \ \ \frac{1 + i}{2} \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}  -1 & -i \\ -1 - 2i & 1 \end{array} \right] \ \ , $$

giving the solution for the system as

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{c} v \\ w \end{array} \right] \  =  \ \frac{1 + i}{2} \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}  -1 & -i \\ -1 - 2i & 1 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 3i \end{array} \right] \  = \  \frac{1 + i}{2} \  \left[ \begin{array}{c} -5 + 3 \\ -5 - 10i + 3i \end{array} \right] $$
$$  = \  \frac{1 + i}{2} \  \left[ \begin{array}{c} -2 \\ -5 - 7i  \end{array} \right] \ = \ \left[ \begin{array}{c} -1 \ -  \ i \\ \frac12·(-5 - 5i - 7i + 7)  \end{array} \right] \ = \ \left[ \begin{array}{c} -1  -   i \\ 1  -  6i    \end{array} \right] \ \ . $$

**ADDENDUM --**

I feel like I ought to show Gaussian elimination while I'm at it.  Starting with the augmented matrix
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|r}  1 & i & 5 \\ 1 + 2i & -1 & 3i \end{array} \right] \ \ ,  $$
we would subtract $ \ (1 + 2i) \ $ times row 1 from row 2 to produce
$$ \rightarrow \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|r}  1 & i & 5 \\ 0 & -1 - (-2 + i) & 3i - (5 + 10i) \end{array} \right] \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|r}  1 & i & 5 \\ 0 &  1 -   i  & -5 - 7i \end{array} \right] \ \ ;  $$
dividing the second row by $ \ 1 - i \ \ , \ $ or multiplying it by $ \ \frac{1 \ + \ i}{2} \ \ , $ then gives us
$$  \rightarrow \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|r}  1 & i & 5 \\ 0 &  \frac{(1 + 1)·(1 - i)}{2}  & \frac{-5 - 7i  - 5i + 7}{2} \end{array} \right] \ \ =  \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|r}  1 & i & 5 \\ 0 &  1  &  1 - 6i   \end{array} \right] \ \ ;  $$
finally, subtracting $ \ i \ $ times row 2 from row 1 yields
$$  \rightarrow \ \  \left[ \begin{array}{cc|r}  1 & 0 & 5 - (i + 6) \\ 0 &  1  &  1 - 6i   \end{array} \right] \ \ = \ \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc|r}  1 & 0 & -1 -  i   \\ 0 &  1  &  1 - 6i   \end{array} \right] \ \ .  $$

So a lot of those devices you learn about in "standard" algebra (high-school or first-year college) where we always dealt with real numbers carry over to calculation with complex numbers (even things like polynomial or synthetic division).

Answer (score 4):

By substitution, $v = 5 - iw$, and so $(1 + 2i)(5 - iw) - w = 3i$.

This implies $5 -iw+10i + 2w - w= 3i$. Rearranging further, we have $5 + 7i = iw - w$ and so:

$$w = \frac{5 + 7i}{i - 1} \cdot \frac{i + 1}{i + 1} = \frac{5 - 7 + (5 + 7)i}{-1-1} = 1 - 6i.$$

Now $v = 5 - i(1 - 6i) = 5 - i - 6 = -1 - i$.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle v+iw=5\ ( 1) ;\ ( 1+2i) v-w=3i\ ( 2)$
Multiply the second equation by $\displaystyle i$ to get (3) and then add (1) and (3)
$\displaystyle v+iw+i( 1+2i) v-iw=5+( 3i) i$
$\displaystyle ( -1+i) v=2\ \Longrightarrow \ v\ =\ -( 1+i)$
and $\displaystyle w\ =\ 1-6i$